# Чем отличаются стандарты c++14 и gnu++14?

Tags: c++, linux, компилятор, clang

Есть ли существенные отличия между двумя стандартами `c++14` и `gnu++14` (расширение `GNU`)? Имеет ли смысл для компиляции под линуксом придерживаться именно 2-ого варианта?

Comment: Ну хотя бы тем, что С++14 - это стандарт, а gnu++14 - нет.

Comment: да, это расширение, но я думаю ты понял о чем я)

Comment: Указание `-std=c++14` приводит к определению макро `__STRICT_ANSI__`, а это в свою очередь "выключает" определения многих системных функций Linux в заголовочных файлах. Например, исчезает `sbrk` , `gethostname` и т.п. Их можно "вернуть", но проще, может быть, не делать `-std=c++14`. Хотя я лично советовал бы придерживаться стандартного языка. Плюс `-pedantic-errors`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Отличие между c++14 и gnu++14 в том, что в первом случае компилятор старается соответствовать стандарту, а во втором включает [различные расширения](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Extensions.html).

- Если Вы пишете приложение только под линукс - то можно не задумываться о том, какой именно ключик выбирать.
- Если же приложение пишется так, что есть небольшая вероятность, что оно будет компилироваться и другими компиляторами (и другие платформы), то лучше указывать std=c++14.
- Если это приложение просто лабораторная работа, то также лучше использовать std=c++14 - в этом случае больше шансов, что у преподавателя в visual studio оно скомпилируется и можно будет получить свою оценку.